# How to design the Tables / Query for (m:n relation?)

Tags: sql, database-schema

I am sorry if the term m:n is not correct, If you know a better term i will correct. I have the following situation, this is my original data:

```
gameID
participID
result
```

the data itself looks like that

```
1     5      10
1     4     -10
2     5     150
2     2    -100
2     1     -50
```

when i would extract this table it will easily have some 100mio rows and around 1mio participIDs ore more.

i will need:

```
show me all results of all games from participant x, where participant y was present
```

luckily only for a very limited amount of participants, but those are subject to change so I need a complete table and can reduce in a second step.

my idea is the following, it just looks very unoptimized

1) get the list of games where the "point of view participant" is included"

```
insert into consolidatedtable (gameid, participid, result)
    select gameID,participID,sum(result) from mastertable where participID=x and result<>0
```

2) get all games where other participant is included

```
insert into consolidatedtable (gameid, participid, result)
where gameID in (select gameID from consolidatedtable)
AND participID=y and result<>0
```

3) delete all games from consolidate table where count<2

```
delete from consolidatedDB where gameID in (select gameid from consolidatedtable where count(distinct(participID)<2 group by gameid)
```

the whole thing looks like a childrens solution to me

1. I need a consolidated table for each player
2. I insert way to many games into this table and delete them later on
3. the whole thing needs to be run participant by participant over
   the whole master table, it would not work if i do this for several
   participants at the same time

any better ideas, must be, this ones just so bad. the master table will be postgreSQL on the DW server, the consolidated view will be mySQL (but the number crunching will be done in postgreSQL)

---

my problems

1) how do i build the consolidated table(s - do i need more than one), without having to run a single query for each player over the whole master table (i need to data for players x,y,z and no matter who else is playing) - this is the consolidation task for the DW server, it should create the table for webserver (which is condensed)

2) how can i then extract the at the webserver fast (so the table design of (1) should take this into consideration. we are not talking about a lot of players here i need this info, maybe 100? (so i could then either partition by player ID, or just create single table)

---

- Datawarehouse: postgreSQL 9.2 (48GB, SSD)
- Webserver:     mySQL 5.5  (4GB Ram, SSD)

  - master table: gameid BIGINT, participID, Result INT, foreign key on particiP ID (to participants table)
- the DW server will hold the master table, the DW server should also prepare the consolidated/extracted Tables (processing power, ssd space is not
  an issue)
- the webserver should hold the consoldiated tables (only for the 100
  players where i need the info) and query this data in a very
  efficient manner

so efficient query at webserver >> workload of DW server)

---

i think this is important, sorry that i didnt include it at the beginning.

the data at the DW server updates daily, but i do not need to query the whole "master table" completely every day. the setup allows me to consolidate only never values. eg: yesterday consolidation was up to ID 500, current ID=550, so today i only consolidate 501-550.

Comment: Are you more concerned with getting the results for 2 players, or with how to get results for all combinations of players?

Comment: somehow both. my original table is lets say 1M Players. I first need to data extracted/consolidated for lets say 100Players - which is the part which will be on the websrv (smaller size, faster queries). then i need the query also for just 2 players (for the queries on the websrv).

Comment: If you care for efficiency, add the design of the table (datatypes, constraints, indexes) and the DBMS you are using, so others can help you. You mention both Postgres and MySQL but it's not clear where the data resides and on which of the two, you want the queries to be running.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you just want a self join:

For all participants:

```
SELECT x.gameID, x.participID, x.results, y.participID, y.results
FROM table as x
JOIN table as y
  ON T1.gameID = T2.gameID
WHERE x.participID <> y.participID
```

The downside of that is you'd get each participant on each side of each game.

For 2 specific particpants:

```
 SELECT x.gameID, x.results, y.results
    FROM (SELECT gameID, participID, results 
          FROM table 
          WHERE t1.participID = 'x'
                and results <> 0)
           as x
    JOIN (SELECT gameID, participID, results 
          FROM table 
          WHERE t1.participID = 'y'
                and results <> 0)
          as y
      ON T1.gameID = T2.gameID
```

You might not need to select participID in your query, depending on what you're doing with the results.

Comment: y, this should work, its just not really much more efficient than mine, or? it will also query the whole table two times as a wole (select x, select y, it will create a tmp table and the select on tmp table)

Comment: Well, you don't need the self-join to be limited to participants x and y, you could return every combination for all participants with the self join, then query the resulting table for particular participants.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another idea that might work, depending on your database (and my understanding of the question):

```
SELECT *
FROM   table a
WHERE  participID = 'x'
   AND EXISTS (
      SELECT 1 FROM table b
      WHERE b.participID = 'y'
        AND b.gameID=a.gameID
     );
```

Assuming you have indexes on the two columns (participID and gameID), the performance should be good.

I'd compare it to this and see which runs faster:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table a
JOIN (
   SELECT gameID
   FROM   table
   WHERE  participID = 'y'
   GROUP BY gameID
   ) b
ON a.gameID=b.gameID
WHERE  a.participID = 'x';
```

Comment: i don't understand, i don't have 2 tables, what is table a, what is table b? (in the first one)

Comment: "a" and "b" are just aliases and refer to the same table.  You didn't give the name of your real table so we just refer to it as `table`.  Yes, it's one table, but you need to refer to it twice.  The first uses a "correlated query", the second uses a "derived table".  Try both using your real table to see which is better.

Comment: ah, i read it wrong, i thought table_a and table_b, the aliases are necessary for "nested" (?) queries. i will test them when i'mt here and report back. but it will take some time, not even the master table exist yet